# Random syntax error in js script, what causes can it be?

Tags: javascript

i'm getting random syntax errors in js files, sometimes in my bundle, sometimes other files, like fabric.min.js which i know works fine, and i can't figure it out.

For example lately i got :

```
bundle.js Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) at 2:261833
```

which point to this function :

```js
return function (t, n, a, o) {
    if (!e(n)) {
        var u, l = !1, h = [];
        if (e(t)) l = !0, f(n, h); else {
            var d = r(t.nodeType);
            if (!d && sr(t, n)) O(t, n, h, null, null, o); else {
                if (d) {
                    if (1 === t.nodeType && t.hasAttribute(I) && (t.removeAttribute(I), a = !0), i(a) && A(t, n, h)) return S(n, h, !0), t;
                    u = t, t = new pt(c.tagName(u).toLowerCase(), {}, [], void 0, u)
                }
                var p = t.elm, m = c.parentNode(p);
                if (f(n, h, p._leaveCb ? null : m, c.nextSibling(p)), r(n.parent)) for (var g = n.parent, y = v(n); g;) {
                    for (var _ = 0; _ < s.destroy.length; ++_) s.destroy[_](g);
                    if (g.elm = n.elm, y) {
                        for (var x = 0; x < s.create.length; ++x) s.create[x](ar, g);
                        var k = g.data.hook.insert;
                        if (k.merged) for (var T = 1; T < k.fns.length; T++) k.fns[T]()
                    } else ir(g);
                    g = g.parent
                }
                r(m) ? w([t], 0, 0) : r(t.tag) && b(t)// error here at 0)
            }
        }
        return S(n, h, l), n.elm
    }
    r(t) && b(t)
}
```

which is a function inside vue, i think it's the patch function.
When browser is restarted, it fixes the issue for some times, but in the end it comes back.

I was thinking about SRI but since we use file:// protocol (app is loaded locally in a webview inside android), i can't do that.

I'm tracking this issue for weeks without success,
how can a valid file become invalid and trigger syntax error ? can it be some cache issue ?

I know it's kind of a broad question, and i don't have much code to show, if you have any idea on how i could debug that or what could be the culprit here, like filesystem/hardware issue.

Thanks.

Comment: it is very much possible that the error is in your code, but javascript is putting in the wrong place.

Comment: But if that was the case the error should not be random ? It's a syntax error after all, so parsing of the file failed, and that file is the same accross thousands of devices, and only one produce that error. It can works for two days before failing, and when it fail, only a restart of the webview make it work again. I'm thinking perhaps the browser has a corrupted version of the file in it's cache

Comment: Random issue just on one browser or multiple? If just one, try incognito session to test. Also delete all cookies, local data and cache associated with the website.

Comment: No only one browser/device, i will try that thanks. Also it's a remote device, i don't have physical access

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question doesnt really have an answer, since this was caused by a file corruption at the operating system level